# Spring java syntax error

Tags: spring

I have a self join class where I want to save a parent object along with the children. To implement that I have:

Model

```
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="checker_id")
    private UserEntity checker;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="checker", orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserEntity> setters = new HashSet<UserEntity>();

    // getter and setter


    public void addSetter(UserEntity setter) {
    if(setters == null) {

        setters = new HashSet<UserEntity>();
    }
    setter.setChecker(this);

    this.setters.add(setter);

}
```

This is the DAO

```
public UserEntity create(UserEntity checker){

      List<UserEntity> list = new ArrayList();
        for(UserEntity setter : list)
        checker.addSetter(setter);

        if (checker != null)
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(checker);
        return checker;
```

I get the error

```
  Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token
```

at this line

```
  for(UserEntity setter : List<UserEntity>())
```

I would appreciate knowing what is missing in the DAO code.

Comment: How does this question relate to Spring?.. It is all about Hibernate or JPA, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that

```
List<UserEntity> list = ...

for(UserEntity setter : list)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have amended the DAO code in the first post. The problem I have is that now when I try to save the parent. The two children are also saved but all in one row with one id rather than three diffrent rows with three unique ids. Is there any problem with the implementation?

Comment: I think you should have something like @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) what I cannot find in your code as well as autoincrement column in DB.

Comment: @user2259555 If you amended the code please also amend your whole question.  It is not making sense now.